# Is it better to access the instance variable or self?

Tags: methods, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

So I have this class `Counter` and a method called `increment`

```
Object subclass: #Counter
    instanceVariableNames: 'count'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Pharo-MOOC'
```

So which is idiomatic or just better to do in Smalltalk/Squeak/Pharo?

```
increment
    "add 1 to the instance variable (count)"
    self count: self count + 1.
```

or

```
increment
    "add 1 to the instance variable (count)"
    count := count + 1.
```

And of course, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: yeah, you're right. The answer I provided is just a subjective answer. Although is more conventional than others ;)

Comment: By the way, and completely off-topic: this is one of the beautiful things about Newspeak. In Newspeak, there is no difference between the two, because in Newspeak, *everything* is a message send: there *are no instance variables*. In fact, there are no variables at all. "Instance variables" are just pairs of getters and setters (or just getters in the case of immutable "variables"). Local variables are just pairs of getters and setters (or just getters) on a `LexicalScope` object. And so on.

Comment: I would not call this question _primarily opinion-based_. And also @EstebanLM 's answer is not. It shows a valid argument for each side and the answer that you do not make a mistake by adopting one or the other method is a valid and thoughtful answer to a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

both are kind of equivalent.
in terms of performance, the compiler will likely optimise those setters and getters so you will not have any extra message send. 
Now, there are advantages and disadvantages in both approaches. For what I can think right now:

- the first one is more appealable for refine in future subclasses (since they provide another hook for modification).
- the second one is (in general) more readable.

If I remember correctly, Kent Beck recommends the first approach in his book "Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns". But, as any pattern, is not a rule written in stone. But also, in general you should avoid to create setters...

In my case, I often go for the first approach, but I put my setters in a private protocol :)